# Why hangs the web page after it started a daemon on the underlying server?

Tags: html, perl, cgi, daemon

I would like to start/stop a daemon process on my home server via a simple web page.

The html is like this:

```
<form action="http://192.168.2.101/cgi-bin/managedaemon.pl" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Start" name="start"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Stop" name="stop"/>
</form>
```

The managedaemon.pl is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
system("/usr/local/theprog/startserver");
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
print "<html>";
...
```

And the startserver is like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr/local/theprog
./theprogserver -daemon
```

When I execute the Perl script from the command line, the daemon process is started properly and the script is terminated.
However, when I trigger it from the web browser, the daemon process is started, but the page hangs until the just started daemon is killed.

Please let me know how could I avoid this 'hanging'.

Thanks,
Marton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your daemon is probably not detaching properly, This [SO Answer about daemonizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize/3095624#3095624) contains a good summary of the steps required

Comment: or just add redirection to the bash script

Comment: I am sure you are right, that this is an improper detach problem. Since the software is not open source, I cannot fix it. However, the /sbin/start-stop-daemon solved my probem. Thanks!