# Service under linux, a modern approach?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The situation: a small new project of a service listening on socket.

Preliminary study: this answer [how to make a process daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384168/how-to-make-a-process-daemon) and the link in the answer: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html

Good, everything fine.

Now, for the listening part I have no problems, but for threads I started to watch C++11 specs. So I included:

```
#include <thread>
```

This is nice, just calling **std::thread**, I can open a thread on new connections.

So I was just wondering, is the **fork** part still good in C++11?

Is there a newer approach to building a Linux service, or is the how-to still good?

Comment: I'm wondering how a good approach for usage with `systemd` looks like…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fork` works well in any language on Linux.  Separate processes not the same as threads, but they do have a few things in common.

`fork()` makes a nearly-identical copy of the current process.  Including all its file handles, memory maps, heap, stack, etc.  However, only the thread which called `fork()` runs in the child.

A new thread runs in the same process, and has potential access to all its resources, including heap, file handles, semaphores, etc.  This is potentially a contention issue since other threads manipulating the same resources can cause hard-to-find behavior.

A daemon is little more than a process which has detached from a terminal and so can continue to run after the initiating user has logged out.  Presumably it makes its own arrangements for writing errors (like into a log), sensing input, processing requests, etc.

Comment: Clear point. So to make it short. Witth c++ 11 the good way to build a daemon is stil forking the process? Nothing usable from c++ 11 new features?

Comment: Wrong on substance. _fork() makes a nearly-identical copy of the current process. Including all its threads,_ - plain wrong.

Comment: @wallyk, because it is a true for all Posix-compliant systems I am aware of.

Comment: @wallyk, it is not what I think it does, it is what the man page says it does. I invite you to check it yourself :)

Comment: @SergeyA:  You are correct.  I have correct my answer.

Comment: So, yes, I will continue to use fork :-)

Answer (score 2):

fork() was never part of any C++ standard, and I do not see it ever to become a part of it. There are certain benefits and drawbacks of doing your service as a multi-process or multi-threaded application. The main benefit of multi-process is resiliance - crash in one service handler will not affect another, while crash in a multithreaded application will kill at all. On the other hand, multithreaded applications have more ways (and those are faster) to communicate to with each other then the ones available to multi-process apps.

The choice is yours, but one thing you NEVER want to do is to mix forks and threads together.

Comment: I heartily agree on that last line. However, forks can use *all* the communication techniques that threads can use: It is possible to map a memory region prior to the fork which will be shared by the two processes even if one of them writes to the memory. Alternatively, a common file can be `mmap()`'ed to create such a region of shared memory. This can be used to implement all kinds of locks and circular buffers for communication. Afaik, that's an optimization employed by some MPI implementations to avoid more heavy-weight kernel calls for intra-node communication.

Comment: @cmaster, the main issue with process communicating over shared memory is that on non cache-coherent systems writing to shared memory is slower than writing into main memory.

Comment: Thank you, have my upvote. Anyway need to ix forks and threads. I mean: I need to build a service. This service must be multithread. There will be just one fork at beginning, like in linked tutorial. I have no better ideas :-/