# Linux & Java - Disown a process from Java CommandLine

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'm running on Ubuntu.
I have Java a program being started from command line using `java -jar myTopJar.jar`.
The myTopJar.jar should do something and than , run a second jar and terminate (the `myTopJar.jar` should terminate and let the second jar run).

In order to run a jar and disowning it (I mean from command line) I used to run this command: `java -jar mySecondJar.jar & disown`.

I expected the same behaviour when I run the command from Java utility that I'm using :

```
import org.apache.commons.exec.*;

public static int execCommand () throws ExecuteException, IOException, InterruptedException {
    logger.debug("About to execute command: ", command);
    CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse("java -jar mySecondJar.jar & disown");
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
    DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
    executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Apache's `commons-exec-1.2.jar` 
Just to make the flow clear:

1. I'm running the myToJar.jar from Linux command line
2. The last line in the `main()` method of `myTopJar.jar` should call the above `execCommand()` method and exit (expecting the `mySecondJar.jar` to continue running).

The result is that `myTopJar.jar` termination, terminates the `mySecondJar.jar` process as well.

Can someone please assist here?

Comment: Maybe running second jar with [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) can help?

Comment: You will need to read a bit about the differences of a raw UNIX exec call and a shell like bash.

Comment: You can't do that in pure Java since it doesn't have access to the necessary syscalls; you'll have to use a shell command such as, for instance, `sudo`.

Comment: have u tried `nohup ..urCommand... &` ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a wrapper for your second call. The wrapper will make the second process a [daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize) properly using a double-fork technique so that the second process will have no connection to the session of the first one. I would write a wrapper in C using `daemon(3)` function if it's available on the system you are going to use.

For example you can use the following simple C code for your wrapper:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
        if (0 != daemon(1, 0)) { /* 1 for nochdir */
                perror("daemon");
                return 1;
        }

        if (0 != execl("/path/to/java", "/path/to/java", "-jar", "mySecondJar.jar", NULL)) {
                perror("execl");
                return 1;
        }

        /* not reached */
        return 0;
}
```

Compile it and call from your first Java program.