# Stop child from reciving SIGINT from parent proccess

Tags: c, multithreading

I have been trying to prevent my parent thread from killing the child proccess if the parent proccess recives a ctrl-C signal. I have run out of ideas.

The parent proccess allready catches SIGINT and so i want the same as now the children dies.

```
  int main() {
       pid_t pid;

       pid = fork();

       if(pid > 0) {
          /*Parent proccess*/
          [...other code...]
       } else {
          /*Child proccess*/

           signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);     //does not work
           sigaction(SIGINT, &action, 0);  //does not work either
           [...other code...]
       }

  }
```

Ideas?

Comment: What is the goal to hold the child alive if the parent process is dead?

Comment: What signal is the child process getting to kill it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux daemonize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize)

Comment: There are no threads here, only processes.

Comment: Why does the child gets signalled at all when the parent ends?

Comment: It usually doesn't, but ctrl+c sends sigint to the whole foreground process-group, not just to the parent process. The OP could try to use setsid() instead of trying to catch the signal.

Comment: The parent proccess allready catches SIGINT and so i want the same as now the children dies.

Comment: do you by chance exec*() after the fork()? This will reset all signal handlers to default

Comment: Yes! ahh so thats it then, i do execvp(). But should not the sig* in parent/child code work for the new proccess?

Comment: File handles, env vars, and process groups are kernel properties. Signal handers are user-space properties. Nothing user-space survives exec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SIGINT` is sent to the entire process group.  Try using `setpgrp();` in the child process to put it into a different process group.