# c++ Cross platform background task

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, windows-services, cross-platform

I'm trying to figure out how do I develop a cross platform program that will run in the background and will work once the system has started.

I want to cover windows and Linux only.  I know that there's no such thing as a thread and there are only processes. 
So..  in Linux I need to make a daemon program or a service in Windows.

I know how each of them works in logical way but I don't have an idea how to write it.

I will appreciate every help I could get. 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you try asking Google? [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize) summarises the steps for Linux. I'm sure similar answers exist for Windows.

Answer (score -1):

You simply need to run your program after system start. It's not related to threads and stuff.

Wrap OS-specific stuff in

```
#if defined _WIN32
    #include <windows.h>
    int ret = ShellExecute(hwnd, "runas", "see link below for windows", NULL, "c:\\windows\\system", SW_SHOWNORMAL );
#elif defined __linux__
     int ret = system("see link for linux");
#else
     #error Err
#endif
```

Link for [Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582108/create-windows-service-from-executable)

Link for [Linux](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html) - for linux case you need to call several commands to create startup scripts and add them to chkconfig