# Detach child process from parent

Tags: unix, posix, child-process

When a child process forked from a parent dies, it still exists to some extent and is left in a zombie state, until it is reaped from a wait() call.

Is is possible to detach this parent-child relationship and have the children be automatically reaped? Maybe orphan off the child to init, or something?

Possible use case: Creating a lot of fire-and-forget processes in a long-lived program, without "holding" on to an increasing list of zombie PIDs that cannot be recycled by the OS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the POSIX _exit() documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html):

> If the parent process of the calling process has set its
>   `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag or has set the action for the `SIGCHLD` signal to
>   `SIG_IGN`:
>
> - The process' status information (see Status Information), if any, shall be discarded.
> - The lifetime of the calling process shall end immediately. If `SA_NOCLDWAIT` is set, it is implementation-defined whether a `SIGCHLD`
>     signal is sent to the parent process.
> - If a thread in the parent process of the calling process is blocked in `wait()`, `waitpid()`, or `waitid()`, and the parent process has
>     no remaining child processes in the set of waited-for children, the
>     `wait()`, `waitid()`, or `waitpid()` function shall fail and set `errno`
>     to [`ECHILD`].
>
> Otherwise:
>
> - Status information (see Status Information) shall be generated.
> - **The calling process shall be transformed into a zombie process**. Its status information shall be made available to the parent process
>     until the process' lifetime ends.
> - ...

In short, to prevent child processes from becoming zombie processes, the simplest way is to call `sigignore( SIGCHLD );`

**UPDATE**

That does impact the ability to wait for *any* child process, which may not be desired.  The [`setsid()` library function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html) allows a process to disassociate itself from its parent:

```
pid_t child = fork();
if ( ( pid_t ) 0 == child )
{
    int rc = setsid();

    rc = execv(...);
}
else ...
```

The disassociated child process doesn't create a zombie nor send `SIGCHLD` to the parent process on my installed instance of Solaris 11.2.

This is an abbreviated daemonization of a "fire-and-forget" child process, only doing what is necessary to prevent creating a zombie or sending `SIGCHLD` to the parent process.  For a much fuller daemonization procedure, see [Linux daemonize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095566/linux-daemonize)

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any solution that doesn't change global behaviour in a program? This solution will change other unknowing parts of the program that might want to synchronize with their children.

Comment: @Shaggi  See the update.  You should be able to use `setsid()` after `fork()` and before `execv*()` to allow the child process to "hide" from the parent, and not create a zombie nor send `SIGCHLD` on termination.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. My last wish is to be able to do this from the parent at an arbitrary stage in the child's lifetime, but I suppose that's not really possible.

Comment: @Shaggi `setsid()` is async-signal-safe, so you can simply create a signal handler function in your child process code that calls `setsid()` on a signal you chose, such as `SIGUSR1`, or one of the real-time signals `SIGRTMIN + n`.  Then, whenever you want to prevent a child process from sending the parent `SIGCHLD`, just call `kill( pid, SIGUSR1 );` to have the child process call its signal handler.

Comment: The update is incorrect. `setsid` won't prevent the child from being reapable / from becoming a zombie. It'll only serve to prevent `ps`, in its default settings, from showing such a zombified child. But it'll still be a zombie nonetheless (and `ps` still can show it as such, e.g., if you give `ps` the child's exact pid).

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring `SIGCHLD` or installing a sighandler for `SIGCHLD` with the `SA_NOCLDWAIT` flag on prevents all children from becoming zombies (/ being `wait`-able).

To do it for a single child, you can either use Linux's `clone()` without the `SIGCHLD` flag or you can double `fork` (or `vfork` if you know how to do that safely)  when starting the child. The child can then immediately `_exit(0)` and be `wait`-ed upon by its parent and the grandchild can go on to do the actual work (reparented to `init` as you say).

(A slight extension of the double fork would be full demonization where the child or the grandchild *also* calls setsid to create a new session, a new process group and to detach from the controlling terminal. Setsid alone won't prevent the child from becoming a zombie. It will just hide the zombie from `ps` in its default settings where `ps` only shows processes in the current terminal-controlling sesssion.)

Answer (score -1):

As of Python 3.2, you can use subprocess.Popen() and pass start_new_session=True to accomplish this.

The docs state:

> If start_new_session is true the setsid() system call will be made in the child process prior to the execution of the subprocess. (POSIX only)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen

Note that this does not allow one "to do this from the parent at an arbitrary stage in the child's lifetime" as mentioned in a follow-up comment.

Comment: We're talking about C, not Python.