# Which process is getting exited and why is close(0) call followed after exit(0)

Tags: c, process, fork, exit

```
if (log_daemon) {
    pid_t pid;
    log_init();

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0) {
        log_error("error starting daemon: %m");
        exit(-1);
    } else if (pid)
        exit(0);

    close(0);
    open("/dev/null", O_RDWR);
    dup2(0, 1);
    dup2(0, 2);

    setsid();

    if (chdir("/") < 0) {
        log_error("failed to set working dir to /: %m");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I have above c program, and couldnt figure out what does the `exit(0);` do in this case, which process does it exit? and what does the `close(0);` is followed for? Will the `close(0);` even execute?

Is this code just to test whether a child process can be created?

**UPDATE:**
ok, I got it from this question [Start a process in the background in Linux with C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407197/start-a-process-in-the-background-in-linux-with-c).

Basically, `close(0);` does is closes current standard input for child process and opens `/dev/null` as input device. This way child process will behave as a deamon and will not read anything from terminal or standard input.

Answer (score 4):

The fork returns the process id in the parent process, and `0` in the child process.  The main calling process is exiting because`pid == 0` so `if (pid)` is true in the parent, and false in the child.  The child then proceeds to `close(0)`, etc.

Comment: Thats what I thought, so parent is exiting in this case and child is taken by init, correct?