# Python Twisted Daemon

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web, twisted.client, twisted.internet

I have written a simple twisted server -

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet import protocol
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Index(resource.Resource):
    isLeaf = True
    def render_GET(self, request):
        args = request.args
        print 'Args: %s' %(repr(args))

print 'Serving on PORT: 8090'
site = server.Site(Index())
reactor.listenTCP(8090, site)
reactor.run()
```

This runs fine on `127.0.0.1:8090`. Note this this runs in terminal (foreground), when I make the process run in background using `nohup` & `ctrl+Z`. the server does not respond to requests. What should I do to daemonize this twisted server

Comment: Are you actually backgrounding it, or just suspending it with ctrl+z?

Comment: well I tried `ctrl+z`. how else do I deamonize it?

Comment: After typing "ctrl+z" type "bg" into your shell. that will resume the suspended process as a background job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As nmichael and Rakis already mentioned, after "ctrl+z" type "bg" to resume suspended process as a background job.

To run it directly as background job, type

```
python myserver.py &
```

To run it directly as background job that won't stop when you logout, type

```
nohup python myserver.py &
```

Also note that `nohup`, is not true deamonization. See the differences here: [What's the difference between nohup and a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon)

If you really want to deamonize your Twisted server, the best option is to use **`twistd`** as Mark Loeser answered.

Comment: thanks. have already done this & it works. since nmicheal's answers was not an actual ansewer, could not upvote or mark...

Comment: This is not really daemonization. For example, when you close your terminal window, stdin, stdout, and stderr will simply disappear.

Comment: @Glyph of course. That's why I have the last sentence *"But if you really want to deamonize it, use twistd as Mark Loeser answered."* I only answered on how to run in the background or with `nohup`, not deamonizing it.

Answer (score 9):

I'd recommend looking into twistd.  That way you don't have to worry about handling any of the start up, pid file management, etc.  The documentation on their site is quite good: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/basics.html.  Also check http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html for how to implement the application file.