# Call to daemon in a /etc/init.d script is blocking, not running in background

Tags: linux, perl, daemon, init.d

I have a Perl script that I want to daemonize. Basically this perl script will read a directory every 30 seconds, read the files that it finds and then process the data. To keep it  simple here consider the following Perl script (called synpipe_server, there is a symbolic link of this script in `/usr/sbin/`) :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $continue = 1;
$SIG{'TERM'}  = sub { $continue = 0; print "Caught TERM signal\n"; };
$SIG{'INT'} = sub { $continue = 0; print "Caught INT signal\n"; };

my $i = 0;
while ($continue) {
     #do stuff
     print "Hello, I am running " . ++$i . "\n";
     sleep 3;
}
```

So this script basically prints something every 3 seconds.

Then, as I want to daemonize this script, I've also put this bash script (also called synpipe_server) in `/etc/init.d/` :

```
#!/bin/bash
# synpipe_server : This starts and stops synpipe_server
#
# chkconfig: 12345 12 88
# description: Monitors all production pipelines
# processname: synpipe_server
# pidfile: /var/run/synpipe_server.pid
# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

pname="synpipe_server"
exe="/usr/sbin/synpipe_server"
pidfile="/var/run/${pname}.pid"
lockfile="/var/lock/subsys/${pname}"

[ -x $exe ] || exit 0

RETVAL=0

start() {
    echo -n "Starting $pname : "
    daemon ${exe}
    RETVAL=$?
    PID=$!
    echo
    [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch ${lockfile}
    echo $PID > ${pidfile}
}

stop() {
    echo -n "Shutting down $pname : "
    killproc ${exe}
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
    if [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ]; then
        rm -f ${lockfile}
        rm -f ${pidfile}
    fi
}

restart() {
    echo -n "Restarting $pname : "
    stop
    sleep 2
    start
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    status)
        status ${pname}
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart}"
    ;; esac

exit 0
```

So, (if I have well understood the doc for daemon) the Perl script should run in the background and the output should be redirected to `/dev/null` if I execute :

```
service synpipe_server start
```

But here is what I get instead :

```
[root@master init.d]# service synpipe_server start
Starting synpipe_server : Hello, I am running 1
Hello, I am running 2
Hello, I am running 3
Hello, I am running 4
Caught INT signal
                                                           [  OK  ]
[root@master init.d]#
```

So it starts the Perl script but runs it without detaching it from the current terminal session, and I can see the output printed in my console ... which is not really what I was expecting. Moreover, the PID file is empty (or with a line feed only, no pid returned by *daemon*).

Does anyone have any idea of what I am doing wrong ?

EDIT : maybe I should say that I am on a Red Hat machine.

```
Scientific Linux SL release 5.4 (Boron)
```

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Instead of writing a daemon to poll for changes, you could use inotify http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify to inform you when a change has happened.  It's easier to code for, more efficient, and can see updates faster.  There's a number of CPAN modules to talk with it. http://search.cpan.org/search?query=inotify&mode=all

Comment: Thanks, this is useful info, I will definitely have a look at Inotify.

Comment: @Schwern : that does not change the fact that I have to run a daemon in the background waiting for inotify notifications, no ??

Comment: That's true.  I can't help you with the details of the daemon command on Redhat.  It differs from system to system.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally re-wrote the start function in the bash init script, and I am not using `daemon` anymore.

```
start() {
    echo -n "Starting $pname : "
    #daemon ${exe} # Not working ...
    if [ -s ${pidfile} ]; then
       RETVAL=1
       echo -n "Already running !" && warning
       echo
    else
       nohup ${exe} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
       RETVAL=$?
       PID=$!
       [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch ${lockfile} && success || failure
       echo
       echo $PID > ${pidfile}
    fi
}
```

I check that the pid file is not existing already (if so, just write a warning). If not, I use

```
 nohup ${exe} >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

to start the script.

I don't know if it is safe this way (?) but it works.

Comment: I used something similar, but used `daemon` alongside nohup to provide output shown when the script has been started. It's more of a visual cue that anything else, since the [OK] message will always return as OK as long as nohup has run:

`daemon "nohup ${exe} >/dev/null 2>&1 &"`

as an example.

Comment: tony, wouldn't this daemon die when your shell terminates?  Or does nohup prevent that?

Comment: Yes, when the shell terminates, the process created by nohup remains alive.

Comment: I tried the daemon/nohup method but I can't get at the PID that way. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe : The shell variable '$!' is the pid of the last process launched in background. Would it be enough for your purposes ?

Comment: @tony: I would think '$!' is enough, but it doesn't come back with anything for some reason. I'm probably doing something wrong. :\

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested if you don't really care about echoing a warning if the script is already running you can piggyback the "daemon" function out of the /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions file as it already performs a check to see if the script is already running.  As such you can use `daemon "nohup $exe 0<&- &>/dev/null &"`.

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to daemonize a process is have it detach from the terminal *by itself*. This is how most larger software suites do it, for instance, [apache](https://github.com/apache/apr/blob/trunk/threadproc/unix/procsup.c#L19).

The rationale behind `daemon` not doing what you would expect from its name, and how to make a unix process detach into the background, can be found [here](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/) in section *1.7 How do I get my program to act like a daemon?*

> Simply invoking a program in the background isn't really adequate for
>   these long-running programs; that does not correctly detach the
>   process from the terminal session that started it. Also, the
>   conventional way of starting daemons is simply to issue the command
>   manually or from an rc script; the daemon is expected to put *itself*
>   into the background.

For further reading on this topic: [What's the difference between nohup and a daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon)

Answer (score 0):

According to `man daemon` correct syntax is

```
daemon [options] -- [command] [command args]
```

Your init script startup should run something like:

```
daemon --pidfile ${pidfile} -- ${exe}
```

Comment: Thanks yko, but it's not this because my 'daemon' usage says : `daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}` . Perhaps we do not have the same version.

Comment: @tony I ended up installing [daemon from libslack](http://libslack.org/daemon/#download)

Comment: The `deamon` @tony is referring to is the one declared by `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28113403/4550233), it seems that the process needs to be sent to the background using &.
Daemon don’t do it for you.