# RedHat daemon function usage

Tags: linux, bash, daemon, redhat, init

I'm working on an init script for Jetty on RHEL. Trying to use the `daemon` function provided by the init library (`/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions`).

I found [this terse documentation](http://www.sensi.org/~alec/unix/redhat/sysvinit.html), and [an online example](http://bitten.edgewall.org/wiki/BittenSlaveDaemonRedhat) (I've also been looking at other init scripts on the system for examples).

Look at this snippet from online to start the daemon

```
daemon --user="$DAEMON_USER" --pidfile="$PIDFILE" "$DAEMON $DAEMON_ARGS &"
RETVAL=$?
pid=`ps -A | grep $NAME | cut -d" " -f2`
pid=`echo $pid | cut -d" " -f2`
if [ -n "$pid" ]; then
        echo $pid > "$PIDFILE"
fi
```

Why bother looking up the `$PID` and writing it to the `$PIDFILE` by hand? I guess I'm wondering what the point of the `--pidfile` option to the `daemon` function is.

Comment: I've tried using `--user=root` and still `daemon` doesn't write the pid file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer the question you guess that you have, is that `--pidfile` is used to check whether the daemon process is already running. On RHEL (and derivates) the `daemon` function won't write the pidfile.

In the case that the program stays in the foreground it has to be explicitly sent to the background by appending `&` to the command and the pid has to be fetched afterwards. `$!` is not usable when using `daemon`.

Comment: The deamon command does not write the pid file, AND does not deamonize the program, seems.. strange.

Comment: `daemon` is a function from `initscripts` which `Starts a daemon, if it is not already running. Does other useful things like keeping the daemon from dumping core if it terminates unexpectedly.`

Comment: `starts a deamon`  is no precise as daemon by specification is a background process. if I need to add a nohup or & on the method, this seems very counter intuitive to me.