# When using RHEL's `daemon` init.d function, how do you capture the PID?

Tags: bash, daemon, centos6, init, sysv

This is a followup to [RedHat `daemon` function usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742227/redhat-daemon-function-usage). In the accepted solution the author states "`$!` is not usable when using [the function] `daemon` [sourced from /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions]". So my followup question is about getting the PID.

**If you want to use the function `daemon` sourced from /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions, how do you capture the PID?**

Answer (score 2):

**You need to create a wrapper shell script that backgrounds your program and captures the PID using `$!` and then pass the wrapper shell script to the  `daemon` function.**

There may be more elegant ways to daemonize a program without using the function `daemon` sourced from /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions but this question/answer is specific about using this `daemon` function. [2]

---

Here's the low level step by step of why:

I shall use `sleep`[1] as a standin for any program that you wish to daemonize using the function `daemon` sourced from /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions.

You are required to create a wrapper shell script that backgrounds `sleep` and gets the PID via `$!`. So for example your `sleep_wrapper.sh` would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 100 &
PID=$!
echo $PID
```

Then you pass this wrapper to `daemon` via:

```
daemon sleep_wrapper.sh
```

If you naively try to call `daemon sleep 100` followed by `PID=$!` you won't get the PID of the process `sleep` but instead:

- you will get the PID for `runuser`
- `runuser` which spawns `bash` process
- finally `bash` spawns `sleep`

[1]
Most binary applications don't background themselves and so `sleep` is a good standin for this example. Obviously to adapt this to your situation you would replace `sleep` with whatever program you wanted to use.

[2]
Seems like there should be better ways to daemonize that do not involve using this specific daemon function.

Comment: Is this not obvious, did it really need a Q&A?

Comment: @123 Taking a peek at your profile it looks like you are very experienced with bash and so maybe this is obvious. But for me this is definitely not obvious. The first time I used this function I used it wrong myself and so I don't want others to have the same issue.  (additionally there is almost nonexistant documentation and the information you do find on google or stackoverflow usually talks about a different `daemon` and so the naive googler may conflate that information with this specific `daemon` from Redhat /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions.)

Comment: Eh, fair enough :)