# Daemonized script fails to start (for Google App Engine)

Tags: bash, google-app-engine, centos, daemon, init.d

I'm trying to daemonize a script. I followed a couple tutorials and came up with the following script (never done it before, just filled in a template, not sure what 345 70 30 mean):

```
#!/bin/bash

# parserservices    Parser Services
#
# chkconfig: 345 70 30
# description: Parser Services
# processname: parserservices

# chkconfig --add parserservices

# Source function library.
. /etc/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

prog='ParserServices for CENTOS/UNIX'

start() {
   # Check that networking is up.
   [ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 1

        echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
   daemon --check parserservices nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh &
   RETVAL=$?
        echo
        [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lock/subsys/parserservices
   return $RETVAL
}

stop() {
        echo -n $"Shutting down $prog: "
   killproc java
   RETVAL=$?
   echo
   [ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && rm -f /var/lock/subsys/parserservices
   return $RETVAL
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
  start)
   start
        ;;
  stop)
   stop
        ;;
  status)
   status parserservices
   RETVAL=$?
   ;;
  restart|reload)
   stop
   start
   RETVAL=$?
   ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
        RETVAL=3
esac

exit $RETVAL
```

This is just a test and there won't be any more java processes running, so killing java shouldn't be a problem (unless someone can provide a better alternative, this is intended to run another script that does some initialization and launches java with the Google App Engine development server).

I copied it to `/etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices` and initialized and started as shown below:

```
$ sudo chmod 755 /etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices
$ sudo chkconfig --add parserservices
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload    
$ sudo service parserservices start
Starting parserservices (via systemctl):                   [  OK  ]
```

But nothing gets started. When I run the script myself it all runs fine:

```
sudo nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh &
root     21510  0.0  0.0 189372  2680 pts/1    S    21:18   0:00 sudo nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh
root     21511  0.0  0.0 113116  1184 pts/1    S    21:18   0:00 /bin/bash /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh
root     21512 27.0  0.2 6619624 37596 pts/1   Sl   21:18   0:00 java -ea -cp /home/centos/gae/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27/lib/appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServ
root     21560  166  0.5 11041848 89188 pts/1  Sl   21:18   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.65-3.b17.el7.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx8184m -javaagent:/home/centos/gae/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.27/lib/agent/appengine-agent.jar -Xboo
centos   21578  0.0  0.0 123356  1384 pts/1    R+   21:18   0:00 ps au
```

By the way, the script's permissions:

```
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 centos centos  155 Jan 12 20:06 start_dev_server_centos.sh
```

This is the output of `systemctl status parserservices`:

```
$ sudo systemctl status parserservices
parserservices.service - SYSV: Parser Services
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2016-01-12 21:05:06 UTC; 18h ago

Jan 12 21:05:06 curator.novalocal parserservices[21266]: Starting ParserServices for CENTOS/UNIX:
Jan 12 21:05:06 curator.novalocal parserservices[21266]: /etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices: Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel] {program}
Jan 12 21:05:06 curator.novalocal systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Parser Services.
Jan 12 21:10:13 curator.novalocal systemd[1]: Started SYSV: Parser Services.
```

Comment: Is there any way to debug what's happening when I run `sudo service parserservices start`? I can't find any log anywhere.

Comment: Should I try getting supervisord instead?

Comment: What does `systemctl status parserservices` show?

Comment: @stee1rat I added the output to the systemctl command

Comment: I'm not sure whether the App Engine has a different `daemon`, but Ubuntu's `daemon` doesn't have a `--check` option (see manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man1/daemon.1.html). Can I ask why you're doing all this instead of creating a systemd unit file?

Comment: @muru, no particular reason. I wanted to know how daemons worked with init.d. Initially systemd seemed like overkill but at this point it's probably equivalent.

Comment: @JosepValls so, does your `daemon` have a `--check` option?

Comment: Yes, apparently that feature is available in RH/Centos. I just found this question and checked my installation's documentation: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216024/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-start-a-daemon-in-rhel-centos-6-init-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is more elegant way to create daemons in CentOS 7.

I see you are mixing classic(SysV) and new(systemd) approach for executing and managing daemons. The classic way, was to create script in /etc/init.d/ as You did, but I see you are using systemctl, which is a part of a systemd. I suggest creating daemon in systemd way.

Remove your script from /etc/init.d and create parserservices.service file in /etc/systemd/system directory, which looks like that:

```
[Unit]
Description=Parser Services
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/your/script/start_dev_server_centos.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Start it with

```
systemctl start parserservices
```

Check it's status with

```
systemctl status parserservices
```

If you want it to start at system startup then enable it with

```
systemctl enable parserservices
```

Execute `systemctl daemon-reload` every time you change the .service file.

Read more about daemons in systemd [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/daemon.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to the message, your `daemon` command seems to be incorrect:

> /etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices: Usage: daemon [+/-nicelevel]
>   {program}

Try to modify ([like suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133238))

```
daemon --check parserservices nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh &
```

to

```
nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh &
```

If you want to use `daemon`, try double quotes:

```
daemon --check parserservices "nohup /home/centos/parserservices/start_dev_server_centos.sh &"
```

This will move the effect of `&` to `nohup` from `daemon`.

If your `daemon` does not support `--check`, remove it.
How to check it?

```
grep -e '--check=' /etc/init.d/functions
```

> **--check=**?*)

`->` supports.

Comment: worked on my Ubuntu (it has no `chkconfig/systemctl/daemon/functions/sysconfig` and I didn't use the corresponding lines)

Comment: Thanks, I want to keep the `--check` parameter and it should work according to the documentation and the accepted answer to this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216024/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-start-a-daemon-in-rhel-centos-6-init-script

Comment: Did you check **your** /etc/init.d/function? It should have `--check=?*)` try `grep -e '--check=' /etc/init.d/function`. If yes, try the last command from my answer (updated it)

Answer (score -1):

You can debug the script with the `-x` option to find out why it is not starting the process as intended.

Instead of calling `sudo service parserservices start`, try `sudo bash -x /etc/rc.d/init.d/parserservices start` to see what is going on and where it fails.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11306816)

Comment: Using `-x` to debug the script should reveal the issue and make solving it possible or even trivial.

Comment: That still doesn't make this an answer.  It's a hint, yes, but not an answer.

Comment: I prefer to tell people how to learn how to get past the problem instead of giving them an answer and 2 days later they run into the next problem and have to ask again.

Comment: @TobySpeight In his first comment, the original author even asks for help to find out what the script does. Which is exactly what `-x` does.

Comment: Still better as a comment.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer states: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful". I think we can both agree that my answer was helpful. I don't see why it should be deleted.