# Can't daemonize Python script

Tags: python, web-crawler

I have a problem with deamonizing of my Python application.

As basic daemon on Python, I have used [this example](http://www.jejik.com/articles/2007/02/a_simple_unix_linux_daemon_in_python/). It works, but only for some simple actions. But when i've tried to deamonize my app - nothing was happen.

[This is my crawler code](http://pastebin.com/xZyhNuLT), (it's too big for posting it on SO) and `Recursion()._recurse(url, 1)` - is the instance what starts crawler (it works independently).

How can I deamonize my application? Thanks to all replies in advance!

Comment: If you have large chunks of code like in your crawler code, please try to find a minimal working example of your problem. In this case start by removing all crawling code and just log something every few seconds. You can use `time.sleep(seconds)` to hold process execution similar to the IO wait of network interaction.
Having less code to look through makes it easier to answer and more useful for others having the problem as you have.

Comment: i've tried to log some message every second, and it was working. For now, I don't understand, why it doesn't working for all crawler...

Comment: Your code does not include the attempt to demonize your script with the Daemon class you are referring to. Please include that. Also specify what "nothing was happen" means exactly. Does your process exit immediately or does it continue to exist but logs nothing and you return to shell immediately or does it just hang?

Comment: When I start the daemon, it must create PID file in /tmp/ dir. So in this case, when I want to start Crawler, inserting `Recursion()._recurse(url, 1)` in run() function of deamon - it exit immediately, and there is no any PID files of my app

Comment: Sorry, but there are too many possible reasons. Try to slowly expand some code that properly works with `Daemon` until something unexpected happens and try to find the smallest change that breaks functionality. Then include the experiment and its result in the question.

Comment: ok, maybe you right. Will try that advice. Thank you!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35510/discussion-between-yakudza-m-and-perseids)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Is not actually daemonizing, but is an approach I've had used and had made me happy when I've needed it*

If you're on Unix you can use [`screen` command](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/grp/cd/soft/epics/extensions/iocConsole/screen.1.html). I've used that for a while to "*daemonize*" Django's Server with a lot of success.

Here are some usage examples:

1. [In Unix, what is screen, and how do I use it?](http://kb.iu.edu/data/acuy.html)
2. [Screen Command Examples: Get Control of Linux / Unix Terminal](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/)

Comment: it works with start-restart-stop actions? I use FreeBSD and Python 2.6.8

Comment: It basically creates a new terminal, where you can start-restart-stop every command (like a normal terminal) and later _detach_ from it. So it will keep running in the background as long as the computer is turned on.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it now. PS: it's not me placed you downvote

Comment: I also didn't downvote you, but - as much as I like screen - yakudza_m asked for a way to implement a daemon, not for a way to put any program in the background.

Comment: @Perseids I see that, just made this suggestion because when I needed to _daemonize_ something time ago, just learned that `screen` will make my life easier according to **the given task**. Sometimes one doesn't know what it needs until it finds it, that's why I suggested this approach and made a notice above the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to run the script in the backround you can use nohup, just add an '&' to the end of the script. For example: python myscript.py &. However this is [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon) from daemonizing

Another option would be to create a [cron job](http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html)

Comment: I've tried that, but then process can be closed, when I close terminal. I need only start-restart-stop actions...((