# Why would my spring boot application will shut down automatically？

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, ubuntu

**update**：
I have followed spring boot deployment for Installation as an init.d Service (System V). I start my application successfully.But, after one day.My application closed again......Is there any ways to help me ?

I hava one spring boot application which names my.jar. I put it into my ubuntu server(20.04) and use the command of ***nohup java -jar my.jar &***.In the first few hours, my application is in good condition.But,after one or two days,it will shut down automatically.

I have seen the log of my application which  don't recorded any error and saved the last correct log before exiting

The current situation is my application is very simple and have only a small number of visits.
According to my guess,it is seems that ubuntu kill my process for inactivity?

My scripts are as follow,

stop.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
PID=$(ps -ef | grep centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }')
if [ -z "$PID" ]
then
            echo Application is already stopped
    else
                echo kill $PID
                    kill $PID
fi
```

run.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo stop application
source stop.sh
echo start application
source start.sh
```

start.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup java -jar centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

I need my application will run all the time.
Is there any ways to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I check the memory usage, so I realized that my spring boot have used a lot of memory abnormally.

I solved it in the following way:
I updated my start.sh with the command of "nohup java -Xms100m -Xmx300m -jar ./target/centre-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar &"

But, I did not figure out why did my spring boot application use a lot of memory?
Is there anyone can explain this phenomenon?

Answer (score 1):

`nohup` is more suited for running processes that are *expected to end* after a while. For example running a lengthy batch script.
As of why it is killed, there may be a number of reasons: memory leak, server security policy .... The server probably decided your program wasn't behaving correctly.  Logs of the server, like `dmesg` or `/var/log/` contents may have some clues about it.

What you said about your app receiving **visits** feels like it is more a *service* rather than a *script*.

You may want to
[daemonize your program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/534648/how-to-daemonize-a-java-program)
. this will make your program tied to the server availability.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958249/whats-the-difference-between-nohup-and-a-daemon) is an explanation of the differences between nohup and daemons.
Also check [this link at baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service) for help on setting up the *daemon*

Comment: I have followed spring boot deployment for Installation as an init.d Service (System V). I start my application successfully.But, after one day.My application closed again.@jjmbourdaret